# upload file from angular2 using web api 2 c#

Tags: c#, angular, file, upload, asp.net-web-api2

I want to upload a file from Angular2 to Web Api 2. As simple as possible.

I cannot really quite understand the type of objects that I have to use.

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Attachment>))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<Attachment>))]
public HttpResponseMessage UploadZip(FormData vale)
{
}
```

Problem is :

> FormData is unknown with a red underline.

Angular:

```
fileChange(event) {
    debugger;
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      let file: File = fileList[0];
      let formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
      this.attachmentClient.uploadZip(formData).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
    }
  }
```

Html:

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,.zip">
```

I really cannot understand the different types of File Objects and how to use them? if you can please Explain to me how it works and what to do to have this.

P.S. I am using Swagger to create the services.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be in the way you are sending the file from the front-end. I can see you are appending to the FormData element correctly (and btw you should use that exact name "uploadFile" to get the parameter on your back-end as well).

However, I don't see the implementation of the uploadZip function. I am providing you with the way I have done it as an example so it might help you:

```
 makeFileRequest (params: string[], files: File[], employee:Employee, 
  doctype:string){
     return Observable.create(observer => {
    let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
        xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    formData.append("file", files[0]);
    formData.append("type", doctype);
    formData.append("employeeid", employee.id.toString());
    let token = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
              //  observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
              console.log(xhr.response);
              observer.next();
                observer.complete();
            } else {
                observer.error(xhr.response);
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
        this.progress$ = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
        this.progressObserver.next(this.progress$);
    };
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/docapi/documents/upload";
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token );
    xhr.send(formData);
});
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you upload data objects to your API. See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2

There is no `FormData` object in C#.

Something like this will help:

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile() 
{ 
    HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request; 
    if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()) 
    { 
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType); 
    } 

string root = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"); 
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root); 

var task = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(o => 
    { 
        string file1 = provider.BodyPartFileNames.First().Value;

        return new HttpResponseMessage() 
            { 
                Content = new StringContent("File uploaded.") 
            }; 
        } 
    ); 
    return task; 
}
```